# contacts/send_email.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, html, contacts

This Php code running behind the contact form. I'm trying to use the same code for two form. But i dont know why its showing

> 500 (Internal Server Error)
>   My Php code is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
<?php
require "Email.php";

    $name1 = isset($_REQUEST['name'])?$_REQUEST['name']:false;

    $email1 = isset($_REQUEST['email'])?$_REQUEST['email']:false;

    $text1 = isset($_REQUEST['21'])?$_REQUEST['21']:false;

    if($_REQUEST['page']=="admission"){
        $phone1 = isset($_REQUEST['phone'])?$_REQUEST['phone']:false;
        $page = "Admission";
    }
    else{
        $page = "Contact";
    }



    $mail = new EMail;
    $mail->Username = 'my email';
    $mail->Password = 'my password';

    $mail->SetFrom("my email","From website");      // Name is optional

    $mail->AddTo("to email","Kalapradarshini"); // Name is optional

    $mail->Subject = "Message From website's $page page";

    if(!$phone1==false){
    $mail->Message ="<table style='width: 100%; font-family: helvetica' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='1' border='0'>
              <thead style= 'background:#9C1519; text-align:left;'>
                <tr style= 'color: white; font-family: helvetica;'>
                  <th>Lorem</th><th>$page Page</th>              
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr style= ' color: #222;'>
                  <td>Name</td><td>$name1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Email</td><td>$email1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Phone</td><td>$phone1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Message</td><td>$text1</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
     ";
    }
    else{
        $mail->Message ="<table style='width: 100%; font-family: helvetica' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='1' border='0'>
              <thead style= 'background:#9C1519; text-align:left;'>
                <tr style= 'color: white; font-family: helvetica;'>
                  <th>Lorem</th><th>$page Page</th>              
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr style= ' color: #222;'>
                  <td>Name</td><td>$name1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Email</td><td>$email1</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td>Message</td><td>$text1</td>
                </tr>

              </tbody>
      </table>";
    }
    //Optional stuff
    $mail->AddCc("","CC Name"); 
    $mail->ContentType = "text/html";               // Defaults to "text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1"
    $mail->Headers['X-SomeHeader'] = 'abcde';       // Set some extra headers if required
    $mail->ConnectTimeout = 30;     // Socket connect timeout (sec)
    $mail->ResponseTimeout = 8;     // CMD response timeout (sec)

    $success = $mail->Send();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

try to help me. Thak you all.

Comment: Check error logs or set proper error_reporting.

Comment: Mail i can recieve but the post data remains missing @u_mulder

Comment: Bad constructor maybe? Try ```$mail = new EMail();``` and turn display_errors on.

Comment: no it didn't help sorry  amenadiel